# Android Dialog theme with round corners

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

So I have created many different dialogs within my app and I have applied to a style to all of them. Like this:

```
custAlertDialog = new Dialog (context, Resource.Style.customizedAlertSlideUpAndDown);
```

This is how I have done `customizedAlertSlideUpAndDown`:

```
<style name="customizedAlertSlideUpAndDown" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/slideUpAndDown</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="slideUpAndDown">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_popup_slideup</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_popup_slidedown</item>
</style>
```

So each time dialog's `.Show()` is called, it slides in from bottom of the screen to the center and when `.Dismiss()` is called, it slides down from center of the screen to the bottom.

Now I want to make all these dialogs' corners round.
How can I do that?

Thanks for your time.

=====================

EDIT:
One of my dialog's XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_height="223dp"
    p1:id="@+id/reLayoutCustomizedAlert"
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="45dp"
        p1:id="@+id/textCustAlertTitle"
        p1:background="#ff548cac"
        p1:gravity="center"
        p1:textSize="18dp"
        p1:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        p1:text="Text"
        p1:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/textCustAlertMesg"
        p1:layout_below="@+id/textCustAlertTitle"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:background="@android:color/background_light"
        p1:textSize="16dp"
        p1:gravity="center"
        p1:textColor="@android:color/black"
        p1:layout_above="@+id/layoutCustAlertBtmBtns" />
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/layoutCustAlertBtmBtns"
        p1:weightSum="100"
        p1:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        p1:background="#ffd5d5d5">
        <Button
            p1:text="Cancel"
            p1:id="@+id/btnCustAlertLeft"
            p1:background="#ff548cac"
            p1:layout_weight="50"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="45dp" />
        <Button
            p1:text="Ok"
            p1:id="@+id/btnCustAlertRight"
            p1:background="#ff548cac"
            p1:layout_weight="50"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="45dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how I am using this layout:

```
var inflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;

// creating view from the layout
var customizedAlert = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.CustomizedAlert, null);

// creating new dialog
custAlertDialog = new Dialog (context, Resource.Style.customizedAlertSlideUpAndDown);

// setting the view as my entire dialog
custAlertDialog.SetContentView (customizedAlert);
```

Comment: using custom view or xml for dialog ?

Comment: the dialog is on my MainActivity.  I have created a layout in XML and that layout is set as the dialog's view.

Comment: I've updated my original post with one of the dialog's XML layout code.  Even if there is a way to do it from this XML code, I would like to know if I can do it via Styles.  That way, I don't have to go back and change it for all different dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create Set custom background to your Parent `RelativeLayout` named `reLayoutCustomizedAlert`

rouund_corner_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>  
</shape>
```

and then Set this Background as

```
<style name="customizedAlertSlideUpAndDown" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/slideUpAndDown</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/rouund_corner_bg.xml</item>
</style>
```

else another option to setBackground

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_height="223dp"
    p1:id="@+id/reLayoutCustomizedAlert"
    p1:background="@drawable/rouund_corner_bg"
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

[**Solid**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) tag is used to setBackground to alertDialog

I'd  used same code and result is following :

set stroke as black so, can see transparency of AlertDialog background.

[image]

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. Do the `corners` and `stroke` has to applied to the dialog itself? Applying this to `RelativeLayout` didn't do anything.

Comment: As you had change `xmlns:android` to `xmlns:p1` so every android property will only be available after `p1:` instead of `android:` check updated code.

Comment: I tried your updated answer as well. It is not working.  I also removed `android:windowBackground` from the Dialog Theme just to test it and now I can see dialog's background around my relative layout.  this `rouund_corner_bg.xml` is having no affect on the dialog itself.  Is there a way to change the Dialog's corners instead of RelativeLayout?

Comment: So I figured out the problem. Your solution was not a prob.  If you look at my XML for layout again, the first `TextView` textCustAlertTitle, was covering the dialog's corners. Because that was colored blue and dialog corners were underneath it.  Is there anyway to clip subbviews? Otherwise, I have to round corners for those components manually.